# Imitate thenAllOf behaviour with CompletableFuture

Tags: java, future, completable-future

I have three `CompletableFuture`s as follows:

```
public Object someMethod(){

    CompletableFuture future1 = CompletableFuture.allOf(futureArray1).exceptionally(this::handleException);
    CompletableFuture future2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> 
        // Here I do something needed for futureArray2 to run );
    CompletableFuture future3 = CompletableFuture.allOf(futureArray2).exceptionally(this::handleException);
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is when the method is called:

1. All of `futures1` to run (can run all of them simultaneously), join to the main thread,
2. `someMethod` returns,
3. `future2` to run
4. All of `futures3` to run after `future2` completes (again, can run all of them simultaneously, the just need the `future2` to finish).

So basically, if I had `thenAllOf` method of `CompletableFuture`, that would have resolve my issue. How do I mimic:

```
public Object someMethod(){

    CompletableFuture.allOf(futureArray1).join();
    CompletableFuture.runAsync() -> // Do something for futureArray2).thenAllOf(futureArray2);
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding. `allOf` does not “run” the futures. By the time, you’re calling `allOf`, these futures may already run or even be already completed; the `allOf` call has no influence on whether or when these futures are completed. All it does, is create a new future, to be completed when all others are completed, allowing to wait for it or chain more operations. Since the `futureArray2` does already exist, it’s very likely that the completion of these already created futures is already on the way.